# StreamTask.getCheckpointLock deprecation and custom Flink sources

Tags: apache-flink

When writing custom checkpointed sources for Flink, one must make sure that emitting elements downstream, checkpointing and watermarks are emitted in a synchronized fashion. This is done by acquiring [`StreamContext.getCheckpointLock`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/source/SourceFunction.java#L263)

[Flink 1.10 introduced a deprecation to StreamTask.getCheckpointLock](https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/10252) and is now recommending the use of [`MailboxExecutor`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/operators/MailboxExecutor.java) for operation which require such synchronization.

I have a custom source implementation which is split into multiple phases. A `SourceFunction[T]`  for reading file locations and an `OneInputStreamOperator` for downloading and emitting these elements downstream. Up until now, I used `StreamSourceContexts.getSourceContext` to receive the   `SourceContext` used to emit elements, which looked as follows:

```
ctx = StreamSourceContexts.getSourceContext(
      getOperatorConfig.getTimeCharacteristic,
      getProcessingTimeService,
      getContainingTask.getCheckpointLock,
      getContainingTask.getStreamStatusMaintainer,
      output,
      getRuntimeContext.getExecutionConfig.getAutoWatermarkInterval,
      -1
)
```

And this context is being used throughout the code to emit elements and watermarks:

```
ctx.getCheckpointLock.synchronized(ctx.collect(item))
ctx.getCheckpointLock.synchronized(ctx.emitWatermark(watermark))
```

Is using the checkpoint lock still the preferred way to emit elements downstream? Or is it now recommended that we use `MailboxExecutor` instead and make collection and watermark inside the mailbox execution thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkpoint lock in source context is not deprecated as there is currently no way around implementing a source without the lock. These sources are already dubbed legacy sources exactly for that reason: they spawn their own thread and need the lock to emit data (push-based).

There is currently a larger rework for sources ([FLIP-27](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-27%3A+Refactor+Source+Interface)), which will offer a pull-based interface. This interface is called from the main task thread, such that no synchronization is necessary anymore. If some async work needs to be done, then `MailboxExecutor` is the way to go.

FYI, new operators should (rather must) only use `MailboxExecutor` instead of checkpoint lock.

Comment: Thanks Arvid. I currently have a source that is split into multiple phases, meaning the file list is retrieved in the `SourceFunction`, but there's a second step of parallel downloading done in a transform function using `AbstractStreamOperator`. So while in the source context the lock isn't deprecated, it is for the mentioned operator. Should retrieving the lock be avoided in that case? What should I pass to `getSourceContext` in that case?

Comment: Yes, in your downstream operator should not use the checkpoint lock anymore. You should use `asyncIO` (`AsyncWaitOperator`) for your second phase or copy and adjust that functionality. By going over mailbox you implicitly get the behavior of checkpoint lock in that there can either be one mail or input be processed at the same time.

Comment: Any particular reason I should go for `AsyncWaitOperator`? Currently the data is being asynchronously fetched from S3 without it.

Comment: It's exactly meant for async operations but usually only small results are returned so it could be inappropriate for you. Nevertheless, you could use it as a starting point. Btw your functionality sounds very similar to the `ContinuousFileReaderOperator` (used by [`fileInput`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/datastream_api.html#data-sources)).

Comment: Thanks! it might sound similar on the surface but there are lots of things happening that I've not mentioned for brevity :)

Comment: I almost thought as much still wanted to point it out. `ContinuousFileReaderOperator` is now also using mailbox model, so it could also be a good starting point to peek at.

Comment: I did look at it, and that's what initially ignited this question :) I actually know Roman (the guy who implemented it) from a previous workplace, trying to get in contact with him directly for some more guidance :)